# What's the best way to handle &nbsp;-like entities in XML documents with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

Consider the following:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

x = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<aa>&nbsp;&acirc;</aa>"""
p = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, resolve_entities=False)
r = etree.parse(StringIO(x), p)
```

This would fail with:
`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 2, column 11`

This is because `resolve_entities=False` doesn't ignore them, it just doesn't resolve them.

If I use `etree.HTMLParser` instead, it creates `html` and `body` tags, plus a lot of other special handling it tries to do for `HTML`.

What's the best way to get a `&nbsp;&acirc;` text child under the `aa` tag with lxml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't ignore entities as they are part of the XML definition. Your document is not well-formed if it doesn't have a DTD or standalone="yes" or if it includes entities without an entity definition in the DTD. Lie and claim your document is HTML.

https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/2008-February/003398.html

You can try lying and putting an XHTML DTD on your document. e.g.

```
from lxml import etree
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
x = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >\n<aa>&nbsp;&acirc;</aa>"""
p = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, resolve_entities=False)
r = etree.parse(StringIO(x), p)
etree.tostring(r) # '<aa>&nbsp;&acirc;</aa>'
```

Comment: The mentioned xhtml dtd is super outdated. Maybe worth mentioning html4 DTD `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 7):

@Alex is right: your document is not well-formed XML, and so XML parsers will not parse it.  One option is to pre-process the text of the document to replace bogus entities with their utf-8 characters:

```
entities = [
    ('&nbsp;', u'\u00a0'),
    ('&acirc;', u'\u00e2'),
    ...
    ]

for before, after in entities:
    x = x.replace(before, after.encode('utf8'))
```

Of course, this can be broken by sufficiently weird "xml" also.

Your best bet is to fix your input XML documents to be well-formed XML.

Answer (score -1):

When I was trying to do something similar, I just used `x.replace('&', '&amp;')` before parsing the string.

Comment: For this to work the encoding must be such that the *&* character denotes   only itself (UTF-8 is one such encoding as [(…) ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). However it still won't work as written because you have to preserve *&* character in already existing Xml escape sequences like *&amp;*. In addition this will mangle plain *&* characters in comments.